# Copy files from on-prem to azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azcopy

I'm new to Azure eco system. I'm doing some research on copying data from on-prem to azure. I found following options:

- AzCopy
- Azure Data Factory (Copy Data Tool)
- Data Management Gateway

Ours is a Microsoft shop; so, I'm looking for tools that gel with MS platform. Also, down the line, we want to automate the entire thing as much as we can. So, I think, **Azure Storage Explorer** is out of the question.  Is there a preference among the above 3. Or, are there any better tools?

Comment: The question is what's the destination? Are you trying to copy data from on-premises to Azure Storage or Azure Data Lake?

Comment: Thank you Gaurav. For now, I'm looking at Azure blob storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing stuff, Copy Data Tool is just an Azure Data Factory Wizard to make some sample data moving between resources. Azure Data Factory uses the data management gateway to get on premises resources such as files and databases.

What you want to do can be made with Azure Data Factory. I recommend using version 2 (even in its preview version) because its Authoring is easier to understand if you are new to the tool. You can graphically configure linked services, datasets and pipelines from there.

I hope this helped, if you need further help just ask away!

Comment: Thank you Martin. How about *AzCopy* or *Azure PowerShell*?

Comment: Azcopy is just a command line utility for powershell if you are using Azure Blob, File, and Table storage. It is very limited and I personally prefer Data Factory for any data movement in Azure. For example if you want to use a Data Lake or some sort of Azure SQL then its not supported.

Comment: Thank you Martin. So you prefer **Azure Data Factory** over any other tools, for copying data from on-prem to azure blob?

Comment: I've never had any problems using Azure Data Factory. I've only used Azcopy when my client refuses to work with Data Factory, and found it uncomfortable because I like to have schedules and configurations in the cloud, not in on-premises resources. Thats just my opinion, if you just want to move a file to a blob and prefer Azcopy, its viable too.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already familiar with SSIS, there's also the option to use SSIS in ADF that enables on-prem data access via VNet.